# Obtaining the last elements of an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a string that looks like this:

```
Current working dir is /usr/local/Cellar/clamav/0.99.4/share/clamav
Max retries == 5
ERROR: Can't create temporary directory /usr/local/Cellar/clamav/0.99.4/share/clamav/clamav-07bc3bfeabec6a3bd40e8c2fdf126323.tmp
Hint: The database directory must be writable for UID 501 or GID 20
```

Running `data=$(echo $string | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')` it provides a variable that looks like this: `0 99 4 5 0 99 4 07 3 6 3 40 8 2 126323 501 20`. I'm assuming this is an array because when I run the following:

```
for el in "${data[@]}"
do 
  echo "${el}"
done
```

It will output:

```
...
99
4
07
...
501
20
```

What I need to do is get the last two numbers in this array *(?)* and put them into a command. How can I successfully extract the last two numbers from the given array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array, you need more parentheses :

```
$ data=( $(echo $string | grep -o -E '[0-9]+') ) 
$ echo "${data[-1]}"
20
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
./my-script.sh | tail -2 | my-next-command
```

or write it to a temp file

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by *[Giles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639457/obtaining-the-last-elements-of-an-array/49639515#49639515)* I do not have an array. I was however able to get the UID and GID into separate variables using the following:

```
data=$(echo $string | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
usersUID=${data: -2}
echo $usersUID
#<= 20
usersGID=$(echo $data | tail -c 7 | cut -c1-3)
echo $usersGID
#<= 501
```